# USB hard drive does not get automatically mounted, and the icon doesn't appear in the launcher

Tags: usb, hard-drive, automount

A USB flash drive is detected as expected and appears in the unity sidebar.  It mounts under `/media/john`, with `john` being my username.

However, a USB hard drive does not show in the launcher.  The only way to access the drive is by doing a manual mount via terminal. This won't be a good solution for the end user, who is not very computer literate.

Comment: I would look at the permissions of the root of the hard drive for clues. Please edit your question and add `ls -l /media/path/to/your/harddrive`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try mounting the USB drive via /etc/fstab ?

I know this does not explain why the drive does not appear in the launcher.
But at least it will auto-mount this way.